# While querying with linq , Max function retrieves upto '9' if more than 9 values in the list

Tags: asp.net, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

While querying with linq, `Max` function retrieves up to '9' if more than 9 values in the list

```
MaxItemNumber = ItemDetailList.Max(e => e.ItemNumber);
```

Here `ItemDetailList` contains more than 10 items, but `MaxItemNumber` is 9, this is not taking into account values above 9.

I need to get max of item number. Please help

`ItemNumber` is string

Comment: What is the type of `ItemNumber`?

Comment: If it's a **string** (why is it a string, when it's called `ItemNumber?`) then it's sorted **as a string**, and thus `9` is definitely larger / comes **after** `10` ..... use the **most appropriate** data type, and then ordering and sorting will also work **as expected**!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:-

```
int temp = 0;
MaxItemNumber = ItemDetailList.Max(e => int.TryParse(x.ItemNumber,out temp) ? temp : 0);
```

Although, if you wanna store `int` then why your type is `String`?